# Is it good to use classes like .left {float:left} and .right {float:right}

Tags: html, css, xhtml

- Which method is more manageable
  specially in team development?
- Which will be more optimized in
  longer?
- What are pros and cons of both?

Stylesheet

```css
#firstblock { background: #000; float: left; }
.genblock { background: #006699; float: left; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="firstblock"></div>
<div class="genblock"></div>
How you should do it
```

Or

Stylesheet

```css
.left { float: left; }

#firstblock { background: #000; }
.genblock { background: #006699; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="firstblock" class="left"></div>
<div class="genblock left"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You should not *leak* presentational information (CSS) to your data layer (HTML).

You should give your elements a class name that describes their purpose. Whether it floats or not is irrelevant in the HTML. *You* decide that in the CSS.

What if you had a class name such as `blue` and then your clients say *we now want all those things red*?

### Example

#### HTML

```
<ul id="primary-menu">
....
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
#primary-menu {
   float: left;
   color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: should we write the same property over and over again when we just need to write it once?

Comment: When did HTML became data layer? Mark-up layer I would say.

Comment: @Andrey Where else does the data go?

Comment: @alex HTML is not purely data, it is itself presentation of data (loaded from server side or hardcoded). It is data + markup.

Comment: @Andrew So it's data, marked up in a format that can be digested by browsers?

Comment: @alex @Andrew I think that's fine, I had a colleague putting data into XML and using XSLT -> HTML just for the web, which I think was overkill. There's no problem (here) with HTML containing data, we're concerned with how it's visually presented in code.

Answer (score 4):

I think the first approach is best.  The problem with using classes like `left` is if one day `left` suddenly needs to float right.  Now you have to change all the classes too.

I would modify the first set of styles slightly to read:

```
#firstblock,
.genblock { float: left; }

#firstblock { background: #000; }
.genblock { background: #006699; }
```

Comment: Yes, that's both a benefit and a drawback. It can be a benefit if you don't ever want your front end HTML devs touching the CSS. But it's a drawback in that your CSS tends to be a bit bigger and you use more individual classes in your markup.

Answer (score 3):

It's ideal to leave any suggestion of formatting out of the HTML (first is better). `firstblock` could be renamed `sidebar` and `genblock` renamed `content` for example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on how your team builds and maintains HTML and CSS.

Using literal class names to define styles (.left = float: left) means that it's easier for developers that aren't touching the CSS to build the HTML. It's more human readable. The drawback is that you may end up with a lot of extra classes that you wouldn't otherwise need of you were using more semantic class names based on the type of content.

I'd say smaller teams should stick with semantic class names for the leaner markup and better separation of content and style. Larger teams can benefit from the more literal and verbose use of classes to make long term maintenance and HTML production a little easier to manage.